# Query always gives a result although it shouldn't

Tags: sql

I'd like to print the number of a room (stanza) only if that room has a reservation (prenotazione) between two dates in order to display an error message in php when the variable with the result is set. The problem is my query seems to check if any room has a reservation set between these dates and always gives output for any room asked.

```
SELECT stanze.num_stanza 
FROM stanze, prenotazioni
WHERE prenotazioni.num_stanza=stanze.num_stanza
  AND prenotazioni.check_in 
    BETWEEN '20190615' 
    AND '20190620' 
  OR prenotazioni.check_out
    BETWEEN '20190615'
    AND '20190620'
AND stanze.num_stanza='100'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it is not good to have WHERE clauses like x OR y AND z. Try (x OR y) AND z. Otherwise if x is true then it will select no matter what z is.

e.g.

```
WHERE prenotazioni.num_stanza = stanze.num_stanza 
  AND (prenotazioni.check_in BETWEEN '20190615' AND '20190620' OR prenotazioni.check_out BETWEEN '20190615' AND '20190620')
  AND stanze.num_stanza = '100'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want exactly -- a full overlap or a partial overlap.

Either way, you can use `EXISTS`.  The following is for a partial overlap:

```
SELECT s.num_stanza
FROM stanze s
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM prenotazioni p
              WHERE p.num_stanza = s.num_stanza AND 
                    p.check_in < '20190620' AND
                    p.check_out >= '20190615'  
             ) AND
     s.num_stanza = 100  -- looks like number so it probably is
```